# How would you refactor this function using Ramda.js?

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to learn Ramda.js but it's constantly challenging to think of how simple things would look in Ramda. If you are a Ramda or functional programming expert, how would you refactor this?

```
const validateFirebaseIdToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Check if request is authorized with Firebase ID token");

  if (
    (!req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")) &&
    !(req.cookies && req.cookies.__session)
  ) {
    console.error(
      "No Firebase ID token was passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization header.",
      "Make sure you authorize your request by providing the following HTTP header:",
      "Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>",
      'or by passing a "__session" cookie.'
    );
    res.status(403).send("Unauthorized");
    return;
  }

  let idToken;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")
  ) {
    console.log('Found "Authorization" header');
    // Read the ID Token from the Authorization header.
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split("Bearer ")[1];
  } else if (req.cookies) {
    console.log('Found "__session" cookie');
    // Read the ID Token from cookie.
    idToken = req.cookies.__session;
  } else {
    // No cookie
    res.status(403).send("Unauthorized");
    return;
  }

  try {
    const decodedIdToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
    //console.log("ID Token correctly decoded", decodedIdToken);
    req.user = decodedIdToken;
    next();
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error while verifying Firebase ID token:", error);
    res.status(403).send("Unauthorized");
    return;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can't reproduce your environment, I can't guarantee that this is 100% working code, however I have verified that most of the functions work as expected.

**Checking the request**

The two sets of conditional statement could be squashed together. Checking the validity of the request and extracting the token could be expressed as follow: *(We’ll take care of the unauthorized case later)*

```
const token = hasToken(req) ? getToken(req) : false;
```

The `hasToken` would check if the request `req` has either a valid authorization header or a `__session` cookie:

```
const hasBearer = pipe(pathOr('', ['headers', 'authorization']), startsWith('Bearer'));
const hasSession = hasPath(['cookies', '__session']);
const hasToken = either(hasBearer, hasSession);
```

**Getting the token**

We can either get the token from the header or from the cookie:

```
const getBearer = pipe(path(['headers', 'authorization']), replace('Bearer ', ''));
const getSession = path(['cookies', '__session']);
const getToken = either(getBearer, getSession);
```

**Generating a 403 “Unauthorized” response**

We could create a function for this too. It could be as simple as:

```
const unauthorized = res => res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
```

But we could also break this down into smaller reusable chunks:

```
const status = invoker(1, 'status');
const send = invoker(1, 'send');
const unauthorized = pipe(status(403), send('Unauthorized'));
```

So that if you wanted to generate other type of responses, you could do:

```
const notFound = pipe(status(404), send('Not Found'));
const serverError = pipe(status(500), send('Server Error'));
```

**Verifying the validity of the token**

We can use a functional approach to try/catch:

```
const verifyToken = async (admin, token) =>
  tryCatch(() => admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token), F)();
```

**Taking back control of `admin`**

The original `validateFirebaseIdToken` function relies on an external variable `admin` which isn’t ideal IMHO. It would be better to have it passed as a parameter. For this we can use `curry`:

```
const validateFirebaseIdTokenFunction = curry(async (admin, req, res, next) => {
  // …
});
```

**Putting everything together**

```
const {
  curry,
  either,
  F,
  hasPath,
  invoker,
  path,
  pathOr,
  pipe,
  replace,
  set,
  startsWith,
  tryCatch } = require('ramda');

const hasBearer = pipe(pathOr('', ['headers', 'authorization']), startsWith('Bearer'));
const getBearer = pipe(path(['headers', 'authorization']), replace('Bearer ', ''));
const hasSession = hasPath(['cookies', '__session']);
const getSession = path(['cookies', '__session']);
const hasToken = either(hasBearer, hasSession);
const getToken = either(getBearer, getSession);
const status = invoker(1, 'status');
const send = invoker(1, 'send');
const unauthorized = pipe(status(403), send('Unauthorized'));

const verifyToken = async (admin, token) =>
  tryCatch(() => admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token), F)();

const validateFirebaseIdTokenFunction = curry(async (admin, req, res, next) => {
  const token = hasToken(req) ? getToken(req) : false;
  const tokenVerified = token ? await verifyToken(admin, token) : false;
  return tokenVerified ? set('user', tokenVerified, req) && next() : unauthorized(res);
});

// This function now “waits” for the remaining arguments: `req`, `res` and `next`
const validateFirebaseIdToken = validateFirebaseIdTokenFunction(admin);
```

**List of Ramda Functions Used**

- [curry](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry)
- [either](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#either)
- [F](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#F)
- [hasPath](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#hasPath)
- [invoker](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#invoker)
- [path](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path)
- [pathOr](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pathOr)
- [pipe](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe)
- [replace](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#replace)
- [set](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#set)
- [startsWith](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#startsWith)
- [tryCatch](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#tryCatch)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was also trying on my end and had gotten 50% up until  unauthorized. It matched almost 90%, I had used `unless` instead of `pathOr`. However, I was struggling because I didn't know about invpker, tryCatch and F. Also, your use of `curry` for "admin" is brilliant!

Comment: I think, instead of `F` in the tryCatch, we should call unauthorized. `const verifyToken = async (admin, token) =>
  tryCatch(() => admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token), unauthorized(res)();`